# Can Tensorflow output the average time of layer or operation？

Tags: tensorflow

When I use caffe,I can use "caffe time" command to output the average time per layer.

Tensorflow has timeline.But timeline just output the time of a operation in one iteration.How to get the the average time per layer or operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no built-in support for it. If you are motivated, one way of getting some stats is to process the StepStats messages in [RunMetadata](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1d76d3e7c7eecddee960c20c9896ccc43d7ccd5c/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L405) (which is what gets fed into a timeline) yourself. You can probably aggregate the running times based on name prefixes.

One thing to note is that depending on your configuration, multiple operations can be running in parallel. Keep this in mind when interpreting the aggregated results.

Comment: Thank you! I think tensorflow concern the time of a operation much. It concern the average time of forward or backward little. When the train has been warm up, the time of a operation in one iteration can represent the average time.